# Setting a background in OnTouch method in android studio

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

i am creating a piano App in android studio. I am using the `onTouch()` method to check if the user has pressed a button and then play a sound. I have created two drawable resources for the piano keys, one is to be used when the piano keys are not pressed and another one to be used when a piano key is pressed. How do i set a condition inside my onTouch() method, to set the background to the respective drawable resources when the piano keys are pressed , and when they are not pressed? Thank you!

Here is the code 
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
...

 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.p1:
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        //set the background to key_pressed
                        soundPoolObject.play(c3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                        break;}
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                        //set the background to key_normal
                        soundPoolObject.pause(c3);
                        break;}
                }
        }

            return true;
        }
}
```

Drawable resource key_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Drawable resource key_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_shadow"/>
    <item android:bottom="10dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
            case R.id.p1:
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        //set the background to key_pressed
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key_pressed);
                        soundPoolObject.play(c3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                        break;}
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                        //set the background to key_normal
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key_normal);
                        soundPoolObject.pause(c3);
                        break;}
                }
...
```

Comment: I just checked, this worked. Thank You so much. Can i use the same process for all the other piano keys?

Comment: @Arnab Yes, other piano keys can use the same way.